# 5 pears and 1 apple cost as much as 2 pears and 2 apples. If each apple costs $0.75,find the total cost of 100 pears and 450 apples.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I know it's in algebra based on the context and the next question is also algebra.

This is what I could do:

$y + $0.75 = $x

$d + $1.50 = $x

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I'm a newbie in algebra. Of course I know d + d = 2d; d x 2 = 2d; 2d - d = 1d. But for more advance a little bit, I don't know already because my school use less algebra but more on real working whether it is possible or not possible to use, particularly the age questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know the cost of $450$ apples, as they are $75$ cents a piece. What you need are the cost of the pears (I will call the price of a single pear $p$). I hope you able to see that your information can be mathematically written as: \begin{equation}
5p+0.75=2p+1.5
\end{equation}
This implies $p=0.25$, or each pear costs $25$ cents. I trust you can finish from here!

Comment: At the 1st place, how do you know p = $0.25?

Comment: Solve the equation for $p$. I subtract $2p$ from both sides and $0.75$ from both sides yielding $3p=0.75$, or $p=0.25$.

Comment: What formatting did you use to indicate the text is Math? The Help Centre doesn't say.

Comment: Google "MathJax tutorial", you can also right-click my equation and select Show Math As -> TeX commands to see what I typed exactly.

Comment: Cool, algebra is so flexible. As for the formatting, just a simple line so complicated